# How can I do list, where every second list element is in a different color with django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to do a list, where every row that can be devided by 2 is grey and every other element is blue. I am thankfull for every!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li class="{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}even{% else %}odd{% endif %}">
```